# Retrieve user from existing table User

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm really new to Symfony and I'm learning how it works.
So I have a DB and a table on it called USER with the fields name,username,password etc etc. 
I'm trying to create a login form that will take the user from that table.
I've already created my enity User
I've read the doc [here](http://symfony.com/it/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html), but it's not what I want, because as i said my entity it's still there.
Should I use FOS user bunble? I've read the doc [here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html) of this bundle, but I didn't get the final part (step7).So my question is, can I use my User Entity with FOS user Bundle? If the answer is no, there is another solution to that, sicne I don't what to change my DB table?

Thank everyone in advance

P.s I generated the User entity following this doc[here](http://symfony.com/it/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html) and this is the resulting class

```
namespace LocalWorker\BackendBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * Utente
 */
class Utente
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $uNome;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $uCognome;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $uUsername;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $uPassword;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $uEmail;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $uRuolo;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $uStatus;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $uDateIns;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $uDateActive;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $uId;


    /**
     * Set uNome
     *
     * @param string $uNome
     * @return Utente
     */
    public function setUNome($uNome)
    {
        $this->uNome = $uNome;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get uNome
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUNome()
    {
        return $this->uNome;
    }

    /**
     * Set uCognome
     *
     * @param string $uCognome
     * @return Utente
     */
    public function setUCognome($uCognome)
    {
        $this->uCognome = $uCognome;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get uCognome
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUCognome()
    {
        return $this->uCognome;
    }

    /**
     * Set uUsername
     *
     * @param string $uUsername
     * @return Utente
     */
    public function setUUsername($uUsername)
    {
        $this->uUsername = $uUsername;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get uUsername
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUUsername()
    {
        return $this->uUsername;
    }

    /**
     * Set uPassword
     *
     * @param string $uPassword
     * @return Utente
     */
    public function setUPassword($uPassword)
    {
        $this->uPassword = $uPassword;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get uPassword
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUPassword()
    {
        return $this->uPassword;
    }

    /**
     * Set uEmail
     *
     * @param string $uEmail
     * @return Utente
     */
    public function setUEmail($uEmail)
    {
        $this->uEmail = $uEmail;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get uEmail
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUEmail()
    {
        return $this->uEmail;
    }

    /**
     * Set uRuolo
     *
     * @param string $uRuolo
     * @return Utente
     */
    public function setURuolo($uRuolo)
    {
        $this->uRuolo = $uRuolo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get uRuolo
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getURuolo()
    {
        return $this->uRuolo;
    }

    /**
     * Set uStatus
     *
     * @param integer $uStatus
     * @return Utente
     */
    public function setUStatus($uStatus)
    {
        $this->uStatus = $uStatus;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get uStatus
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getUStatus()
    {
        return $this->uStatus;
    }

    /**
     * Set uDateIns
     *
     * @param \DateTime $uDateIns
     * @return Utente
     */
    public function setUDateIns($uDateIns)
    {
        $this->uDateIns = $uDateIns;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get uDateIns
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUDateIns()
    {
        return $this->uDateIns;
    }

    /**
     * Set uDateActive
     *
     * @param \DateTime $uDateActive
     * @return Utente
     */
    public function setUDateActive($uDateActive)
    {
        $this->uDateActive = $uDateActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get uDateActive
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUDateActive()
    {
        return $this->uDateActive;
    }

    /**
     * Get uId
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getUId()
    {
        return $this->uId;
    }
}
```

Comment: The step 7 in the link you provided will just create table user in your db. you seem to miss some parts of the tutorial since your entity did not extend `BaseUser`

Comment: I know that it doesn't extends BaseUser, this is the code of the "pure" entity after I generated it with doctrine

Comment: `FOSUserBunle` is a code writter by experts so it's a good practice to use it and not reinvent the wheel. if you decided to do so and had errors please add details about the error maybe I could help